# Автоматическое нажатие кнопки

Tags: php, javascript

Есть страница, на которой необходимо заполнить одно поле и нажать кнопку, после чего меня перекидывает на другую страницу, где также есть кнопка

```
<form action="<?php echo $res["data"]["url"]; ?>" method="POST">
        <button>Оплатить</button>
    </form>
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы кнопка Оплатить нажималась автоматически и меня сразу перекидывало на новую страницу? Cпасибо.

Comment: Есть вариант использовать 
document.getElementById("").click(); Но есть ли что-то мнгновенное?

Comment: не совсем понятен вопрос, что мешает вам сразу на нужный url отправить запрос? А вообще, на форме вызвать событие submit

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял :

Если вы хотите подождать пока в форму введут все данные, то берем **onchange()** и посылаем post запрос через JS

Если вы хотите сразу же повесить на frame/компоненте/странице при загрузке страницы чтобы что-то происходило, то к body-элементу мы можем привязать обработчик **onload()**

```
<body onload="doSomething()"></body>

<script>
  function doSomething(){
    alert('tratata');
  }
</script>
```